# MAAS network configuration error and issue

Tags: networking, maas, dhcp

I have tried a couple times to get MAAS up and running and the issues seems to be incorrect network configuration.  I have a server with 2 net ports. EM1 is the network for MAAS and the servers that will use PXE to boot.  EM2 is the dhcp internet network.  So the interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
   address 10.0.0.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.0.0.2   
   network 10.0.0.0
   broadcast 10.0.0.255
   dns-nameservers 10.0.0.2

auto em2
iface em2 inet dhcp
```

the sysctl.conf file has port forwarding turned on with net.ipv4.ip_forward=1.

the intent is that the `10.0.0.0` network is the MAAS network and the MAAS controller is the DNS / DHCP and router for the PXE clients on the `10.0.0.0` network.  the `192.168.3.0` network is the internet access.

With this config (`10.0.0.0` is the primary network) I can ping 3.66 (myself), 3.1 (the dhcp router address and that is it.  Trying to ping the outside of the 3.1 router to access the internet is unreachable.  I have tried setting default routes but it always says the file exists.

I need to get the configuration correct so that the PXE servers will see the `10.0.0.2` server as their DHCP and I need to get the MAAS server to reach the internet.

Any help in getting this configuration correct would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take out **gateway 10.0.0.2** you can't be your own gateway

Answer (score 0):

take out gateway 10.0.0.2 you can't be your own gateway